# Delphi - E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Char' - Any ideas

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've been tasked with porting a legacy Delphi application over to C# .Net.  The original delphi developer left several months before I was hired.  I'm receiving the:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Char' error

for the below method.  I'm trying to compile the application within the Delphi 2007 IDE, I've been told that original application is either Delphi 4 or 5 if that helps any.  I understand what the error is telling me but I don't understand why\how it is applied to the code snippet below.  Any help\direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance - not sure if I've over done it on the code.

Upper definition:

```
Upper: array[1..256] of Char =
(#$00,#$01,#$02,#$03,#$04,#$05,#$06,#$07,#$08,#$09,#$0A,#$0B,#$0C,#$0D,#$0E,#$0F,
 #$10,#$11,#$12,#$13,#$14,#$15,#$16,#$17,#$18,#$19,#$1A,#$1B,#$1C,#$1D,#$1E,#$1F,
 #$20,#$21,#$22,#$23,#$24,#$25,#$26,#$27,#$28,#$29,#$2A,#$2B,#$2C,#$2D,#$2E,#$2F,
 #$30,#$31,#$32,#$33,#$34,#$35,#$36,#$37,#$38,#$39,#$3A,#$3B,#$3C,#$3D,#$3E,#$3F,
 #$40,#$41,#$42,#$43,#$44,#$45,#$46,#$47,#$48,#$49,#$4A,#$4B,#$4C,#$4D,#$4E,#$4F,
 #$50,#$51,#$52,#$53,#$54,#$55,#$56,#$57,#$58,#$59,#$5A,#$5B,#$5C,#$5D,#$5E,#$5F,
 #$60,#$41,#$42,#$43,#$44,#$45,#$46,#$47,#$48,#$49,#$4A,#$4B,#$4C,#$4D,#$4E,#$4F,
 #$50,#$51,#$52,#$53,#$54,#$55,#$56,#$57,#$58,#$59,#$5A,#$7B,#$7C,#$7D,#$7E,#$7F,
 #$80,#$81,#$82,#$83,#$84,#$85,#$86,#$87,#$88,#$89,#$8A,#$8B,#$8C,#$8D,#$8E,#$8F,
 #$90,#$91,#$92,#$93,#$94,#$95,#$96,#$97,#$98,#$99,#$9A,#$9B,#$9C,#$9D,#$9E,#$9F,
 #$A0,#$A1,#$A2,#$A3,#$A4,#$A5,#$A6,#$A7,#$A8,#$A9,#$AA,#$AB,#$AC,#$AD,#$AE,#$AF,
 #$B0,#$B1,#$B2,#$B3,#$B4,#$B5,#$B6,#$B7,#$B8,#$B9,#$BA,#$BB,#$BC,#$BD,#$BE,#$BF,
 #$C0,#$C1,#$C2,#$C3,#$C4,#$C5,#$C6,#$C7,#$C8,#$C9,#$CA,#$CB,#$CC,#$CD,#$CE,#$CF,
 #$D0,#$D1,#$D2,#$D3,#$D4,#$D5,#$D6,#$D7,#$D8,#$D9,#$DA,#$DB,#$DC,#$DD,#$DE,#$DF,
 #$E0,#$E1,#$E2,#$E3,#$E4,#$E5,#$E6,#$E7,#$E8,#$E9,#$EA,#$EB,#$EC,#$ED,#$EE,#$EF,
 #$F0,#$F1,#$F2,#$F3,#$F4,#$F5,#$F6,#$F7,#$F8,#$F9,#$FA,#$FB,#$FC,#$FD,#$FE,#$FF);

function StrIComp_JOH_PAS_1(const Str1, Str2: PChar): Integer;
var
  Ch1, Ch2 : Char;
  Offset   : Integer;
  PStr     : PChar;
begin;
  PStr   := Str1;
  Offset := Str2 - PStr;
  repeat
    Ch1 := Upper[PStr^];
    Ch2 := Upper[PStr[Offset]];
    if (Ch1 = #0) or (Ch1 <> Ch2) then
      Break;
     Inc(PStr);
  until False;
  Result := Integer(Ch1) - Integer(Ch2);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you have has had an incorrect modification made to the `Upper` constant.  It should be:

```
Upper: array[Char] of Char = ....
```

Of course, even better would be to simply throw this routine away and use the version of [`StrIComp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrIComp) that is shipped with Delphi in the `SysUtils` unit. There seems little point in grappling with this when simply deleting the code will result in a program that is correct.

---

Since you are porting this to C# you can simply use [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) and pass `true` to the `ignoreCase` parameter.

<sub>Thanks to @Ulrich for recognising that this code originates from the FastCode project.</sub>

Comment: +1 I think "Upper" is defined as "Upper: array[Char] of Char;" where each char will be 'uppercased'

Comment: @dorin that would compile. More likely to be array[char] of integer

Comment: could be, why do you think so?

Comment: @dorin because everything else compiles so the compiler error must be there and that's the only way I can imagine that compiler error arising

Comment: +1. I'd give you a second +1 if I could for the blacklist suggestion. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for your suggestion.  It will be the first thing I try on Monday morning.  I just want to get the application compiled.  Getting it to compiled will at least get me a step closer to starting the port over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried your suggestion but I'm still receiving the same error.  The Upper is an array of chars.  You were also correct that the lines highlighted are the ones providing the wonderful compiler errors.  I've updated the question to include the definition for upper. Thanks

Comment: @zeencat Thanks for the edit which includes the definition of `Upper`. It turns out my guess was wrong. Instead of if being `array [char] of Integer` it was `array [Integer] of char`. Anyway, my updated answer will make your program compile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you so much.  I will no doubt be posting a few others questions when I run into trouble.

Comment: Guessing from its name the routine seems to come from the [FastCode StrIComp challenge](http://fastcode.sourceforge.net/challenge_content/StrIComp.html).

Comment: @Ulrich Of course in the FastCode version, the definition of Upper is correct and the code compiles! I still think it is poor code because it is so opaque and the use of `Offset` is quite dreadful.

Comment: I believe you guys are correct as to the origin of the code.  The Classes do begin with FastCode.  I just want to get the dam thing compiled so I can start stepping through and gather requirements for a rewrite.

Comment: @zeencat the original version of the FastCode stuff has a different definition of `Upper`. If you plug that into your code, then the code in your question will compile and work. But you can simply delete all of this code and use the `StrIComp` that is defined in SysUtils. It's rather pointless using an optimised version for your use case.

Comment: The original definition of Upper was changed because the compiler complained about the array [1..MaxInt] of Char line.  I changed this to 256 since it was setting the value of the array to 256 hex characters.  Your right about spending the time converting it.  I just want it to compile so I can work out what exactly the application does.  I beg to wonder what the original developer was thinking when he put all this together.

Comment: @zeencat Well, `[1..MaxInt]` is wrong too. It should of `array [char] of char`. But just delete this routine. Really, just delete it. Then the compiler will use the identically named function in SysUtils.

Answer (score 2):

Is there **const Upper** definition in your pascal module?
If not, get it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/cnpack/source/browse/trunk/cnwizards/Source/ThirdParty/FastCode/FastcodeStrICompUnit.pas?r=425)

Comment: Also, I think Char and PChar will have to be changed to AnsiChar and PAnsiChar with newer versions of Delphi (D2009+)

Comment: @J... zeencat appears to be using an ANSI Delphi, 2007

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Aye, I missed that.  I must have been momentarily transfixed by the creativity of OP's snippet.